# Open list of file in MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, pdf

I need to return a list of file to an MVC controller and open them with JQuery (or Angular).

```
public class QuietanzaPdf
{
    public QuietanzaPdf()
    {
    }

    public string QuietanzaBody { get; set; }
    public string QuietanzaName { get; set; }
}

[HttpPost]
public List<QuietanzaPdf> GetPdfs()
{
List<QuietanzaPdf> listaPdfQuietanza = new List<QuietanzaPdf>();
foreach (var objectQuietanza in listOfPdf)
            {    
                listaPdfQuietanza.Add(new QuietanzaPdf()
                {
                    QuietanzaBody = objectQuietanza.Contents,
                    QuietanzaName = objectQuietanza.FileName
                });
            }
return listaPdfQuietanza; 
}
```

Now i need to open each file in a separate tab of chrome (or download in Explorer) with JQuery (or Angular is also good).

Comment: Check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open

Comment: Thank you but the content returned is a base64 string not an URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be nice to be able to do things this way, but unfortunately it's not very practical and any approach I've seen has had major browser compatibility issues (e.g. using JavaScript's window.open on base64 data). Generally, you'll split up the requests such that there is one request/response pair per PDF file.

A common way to deal with this is to have a one method that returns JSON list with resource identifiers (e.g. a primary key or filename), then to have client-side code (such as jQuery or Angular as you mentioned) fetch each one of those resources with its own AJAX request.

Comment: Yes, it's the solution i had implemented. Thank you